# How can I find the type of a property in an expression when the generic type is object?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression-trees

I have an linq expression that is meant to pass a property around to methods that need it. **But I cannot know the type of the property until runtime.** I need to be able to find out the original type of the parameter that is represented by the expression, but it always shows up at `System.Object`.

I have the following example class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following expression where the 2nd generic type is `System.Object`:

```
Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> expression = x => x.SomeProp;
```

I need to be able to pass the following test:

```
public void PropertyShouldBeInt()
{
    Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> expression = x => x.SomeProp;
    Assert.AreEqual(expression.Body.Type, typeof(int));
}
```

I realize the problem is rooted in that my expression specifies `object` as the property type. But I'm passing in an `int` property. It seems reasonable to me that I should be able to find out the actual type of the property that has been passed to the expression. Take the following test for example:

```
public void AnObjectShouldKnowThatItIsAlsoSomethingElse()
{
    object someObject = new SomeClass();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(someObject, typeof (SomeClass));            
}
```

I feel like I should be able to reference the `SomeClass` type and compare the properties to find the original type. Your suggestions as to how to do that would be appreciated. OR, if you have a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

**EDIT (after solution was found):**

After the excellent answer below, I thought I'd post the working version of my test in case others have the same issue:

```
public void PropertyShouldBeInt()
{
    Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> expression = x => x.SomeProp;
    Assert.AreEqual(((UnaryExpression) expression.Body).Operand.Type, typeof (int));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> expression = x => x.SomeProp;
PropertyShouldBe<int>(expression);

// ...

public void PropertyShouldBe<T>(Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> expr)
{
    // error-checking etc removed for brevity

    MemberExpression me;
    switch (expr.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
        case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            var ue = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
            me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
            break;
        default:
            me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            break;
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(me.Type, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: I was just looking at the UnaryExpression type and saw the Operand property. That's exactly what I was looking for. Excellent answer.

Answer (score -1):

It shows up as `object` because you say it should be `object` when you do

```
Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>>
```

If you want it to be `int`, it should be

```
Expression<Func<SomeClass, int>>
```

---

What I am trying to get across is that you are passing something that explicitly states itself to be of type `object` to `typeof`, then asking why it isn't giving you `int`. Maybe this would suffice?

```
Assert.AreEqual(expression().GetType(), typeof(int))
```

Comment: I need the expression to stay the way it is. Instead, I need to be able to find out the actual type of the property. As I stated, I cannot know the type of the property until runtime, so I can't hard-code the expression to take an int.

Comment: You are essentially asking "why is `typeof(object)` not `int`?"

Comment: See my edits. Even though an object is an `object`, it should still know what else it is (int, string, etc).